# How get the values of a text field with mootools?

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

Hi i have in my form a text field like this

```
<input type="text" name="optionsArray[]" class="pollOptionInput">
```

and i want to get those values they can be value 1 = 123 value 2= foo value 3= bar etc the list can go on.

i want to get those values so i can pass them to my controller via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if I read this correctly - are all the fields going to have the same name?

if so, this works:

```
var vals = document.getElements("input.pollOptionInput[name='optionsArray[]']").get("value");
console.log(vals);
```

on markup

```
<input type="text" value="foo" name="optionsArray[]" class="pollOptionInput">

<input type="text" value="boo" name="optionsArray[]" class="pollOptionInput">

<input type="text" value="bar" name="optionsArray[]" class="pollOptionInput">
```

results in:

`["foo", "boo", "bar"]`

you need mootools 1.2+ to be guaranteed parsing of the name property as is, it will fail in 1.11/1.12

update:

```
new Request.JSON({
    'method': 'post',
    'url': en4.core.baseUrl + 'wall/createpoll/',
    'data': {
        'poll_title': poll_title,
        'poll_description': poll_description,
        'poll_privacy': poll_privacy,
        'poll_comment': poll_comment,
        'options': vals
    }
}).send();

new Request.JSON({
    'method': 'post',
    'url': en4.core.baseUrl + 'wall/createpoll/',
    'data': document.id("formName") // serialize all input fields of a form.
}).send();
```

Comment: it works i mean it does  get all the values but how do i pass them into my ajax json here's what i have var request = new `Request.JSON({
            'method' : 'post',
            'url' :  en4.core.baseUrl + 'wall/createpoll/',
            'data' : {
                'poll_title' : poll_title,
                'poll_description': poll_description,
                'poll_privacy': poll_privacy,
                'poll_comment': poll_comment,
                'options': vals
                                 
            },` it's that correct ?

Comment: you can just create an object (as you do) or you can pass on a form element, which mootools will serialise for you.

Comment: can you please give me an example how to do it i'm a beginner in this